Split a a text column into two parts based on a variable word in R
I have this data frame
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
text = c("A big basket of fruits having apples, green bananas, and peaches",
"A small basket of fruits having green bananas, apples, and peaches",
"A red colored basket of fruits having peaches, green bananas, and apples"),
splitter = c("apples", "bananas", "peaches"))

I want to split the "text" column into two new columns ("preamble" and "body") based on the "splitter" variable. Everything before the splitter will be in the "preamble" column and everything after in the "body" column. The result should be:
df$preamble <- c("A basket of fruits having", "A small basket of fruits having", "A red colored basket of fruits having")

I have tried sub, gsub, str_split. Nothing seems to work. A dplyr style code would be most helpful.

Here is a solution using functions from stringr.
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                 text = c("A big basket of fruits having apples, green bananas, and peaches",
                          "A small basket of fruits having green bananas, apples, and peaches",
                          "A red colored basket of fruits having peaches, green bananas, and apples"),
                 splitter = c("apples", "bananas", "peaches"))
df |> mutate(preamble = str_sub(text,start=1,end=str_locate(text,splitter)[,1] -2),
             body = str_sub(text,start=str_locate(text,splitter)[,1]))
#>   ID                                                                     text
#> 1  1         A big basket of fruits having apples, green bananas, and peaches
#> 2  2       A small basket of fruits having green bananas, apples, and peaches
#> 3  3 A red colored basket of fruits having peaches, green bananas, and apples
#>   splitter                              preamble
#> 1   apples         A big basket of fruits having
#> 2  bananas A small basket of fruits having green
#> 3  peaches A red colored basket of fruits having
#>                                 body
#> 1 apples, green bananas, and peaches
#> 2       bananas, apples, and peaches
#> 3 peaches, green bananas, and apples

Created on 2024-10-19 with reprex v2.1.1

Excellent! This works. I have a question: what does the [,1] and -2 mean?

The str_locate() function returns a matrix with two columns, the start and end location of the targeted text. We only want the start location, so I selected the first column with [,1]. The [,1] means "all rows, first column". The -2 pushes the location back to the end of the last word of the preceding text. The location is the first letter of the targeted text. You don't want that or the space preceding it, and -2 shortens the text pulled by str_sub() to exclude them.

I like @FJCC answer for it's completeness. This, while incomplete, shows how similar could be accomplished using base:
# extracting 'preamble'
regmatches("A big basket of fruits having apples, green bananas, and peaches",
regexpr(" apples,", "A big basket of fruits having apples, green bananas, and peaches"),
invert = TRUE)[[1]][1]
[1] "A big basket of fruits having"

# and it's friend postamble
strsplit("A big basket of fruits having apples, green bananas, and peaches",
 "having", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][2]
[1] " apples, green bananas, and peaches"


stringr build upon stringi uses the ICU regex engine, while base functions use TRE regex engine, unless perl = true.

You can use stringr::str_match:
df[c("preamble", "body")] <- stringr::str_match(
  df$text, glue::glue("(.*) ({df$splitter}.*)")
)[, 2:3]


This is interesting too. Can you please explain the regex logic?

If given regex matches string, it will extract it alongside groups (regex in brackets). Here regex is defined as: group1 + white space + group2. Group1 is everything before the whitespace before spliter andgroup2 is from splitter to the end.
